# Unable to connect to my site even though I am getting a response

Tags: web-applications

My site is unavailable to be accessed at times. It just times out in the browser. I am not able to access the cpanel during this time either. However, when I go into command prompt and ping the host address/ip, I am still receiving normal response times as if the site was running just fine.

Any idea what is happening? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you check your IIS if it is started?

Comment: Why is this tagged as SQL and SQL-Server, what is your site running under?  I added web-applications but adding a scripting/programming language might help also.  When you say unavailable are you getting 500 errors, 404's, or another error?  Have you checked your server logs?

Comment: Ping responses != site running. It means the *server* is running, which is an entirely different (though important) thing.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses. It's timing out to the "Oops! This link appears broken" chrome message. Which I believe is a 500 error. On firefox it just tries to load the page for about 5 minutes and stays a blank white screen. I'll try to provide some server logs asap.